# BarGraph with Primary and Secondary axis in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a dataframe which I would like to create a bargraph with primary and secondary axes.

```
geom_bar(data=top_ten_S, aes(x=Combination, y=AvgTopline), stat="identity",fill="red") +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(
    data=top_ten_S,
    aes(
      x=Combination, y=AvgTopline,
      label=paste0("R",round(AvgTopline,0)),
      hjust=ifelse(AvgTopline < max(top_ten_S$AvgTopline) / 1.5, -0.1, 1.1), # <- Here lies the magic
    ),
  )
```

my df looks like

```
top_ten_S <- data.frame(Combination = c("a", "b", "c"),
                    Nrcustomers = c(20, 200, 1900),
                    AvgTopline = c(1000,3000,1500))
```

I am only able to plot one column with the above code - I would like to a secondary axes so that I could plot Combination against NrCustomers and AvgTopline in

Comment: Not sure if it is related to the thing you are trying to do, but here is a [previous so question regarding two different y-axis with an answer from Hadley Wickham](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales)

Comment: it is but not directly because I have numerical values, on different scales. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1

```
top_ten_S %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Combination) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Combination, y = value, fill = key)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  labs(fill = "")
```

Method 2

```
top_ten_S %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Combination) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Combination, y = value, fill = key)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_grid(. ~ key)
```

Edit: Method 2

```
top_ten_S %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Combination) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Combination, y = value, fill = key)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_grid(. ~ key, space = "free_y", scales = "free_y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60))
```

Comment: This helps, however my challenge is that the y axis i.e.(AvgTopline and NrCustomers) are not on the same scale, thus affecting how the graphs looks like. furthermore my Combination values consists of strings made that are atleast 15 characters in length.

Comment: To handle different scales, set `scales = "free_y"` in `facet_grid`. See `?ggplot2::facet_grid`. To handle large text length, you may print x axis text at an angle. Please see the edit for clarification.